# Why can't I access html canvas in vue?

Tags: vue.js, canvas

I'm trying to make a canvas element in vue. I'm having trouble with the canvas instance. I believe I'm not declaring or using it properly. The error i get is:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'linewidth' of null at
>   VueComponent.draw (HelloWorld.vue?140d:55)

How can I access

My Template:

```
  <div id="app">
    <canvas
      v-on:mousedown="startPainting()"
      v-on:mouseup="finishedPainting()"
      v-on:mousemove="draw()"
      id="canvas"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
```

My js

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  data: () => ({
    canvas: null,
    ctx: null,
    message: "Henlo vue!",
    vueCanvas: null,
    painting: false
  }),

  mounted() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.vueCanvas = ctx;
  },

  methods: {
    startPainting: function() {
      this.painting = true;
      console.log(this.painting);
    },
    finishedPainting: function() {
      this.painting = false;
      console.log(this.painting);
    },
    draw: function(e) {
      if (this.painting) {
        console.log("henlo painting!");
        this.ctx.linewidth = 10;
        this.ctx.lineCap = "round";
        this.ctx.linTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        this.ctx.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few Issues Here:

- Its actually `lineWidth`, not `linewidth`.
- You are using `this.ctx` but `ctx` is set to `this.vueCanvas = ctx`. So, you need to use `this.vueCanvas` instead.
- Its actually `lineTo`, not `this.ctx.linTo`.
- You are using `draw: function(e)`, but have not passed the event in the template. You need to first pass it like `v-on:mousemove="draw($event)"`.

**Working Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#myApp",
  data: () => ({
    canvas: null,
    ctx: null,
    message: "Hello Vue!",
    vueCanvas: null,
    painting: false
  }),

  mounted() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.vueCanvas = ctx;
  },

  methods: {
    startPainting: function() {
      this.painting = true;
      //console.log(this.painting);
    },
    finishedPainting: function() {
      this.painting = false;
      //console.log(this.painting);
    },
    draw: function(e) {
      if (this.painting) {
        //console.log("henlo painting!");
        this.vueCanvas.lineWidth = 10;
        this.vueCanvas.lineCap = "round";
        this.vueCanvas.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        this.vueCanvas.stroke();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="myApp">
  <canvas
      v-on:mousedown="startPainting()"
      v-on:mouseup="finishedPainting()"
      v-on:mousemove="draw($event)"
      id="canvas" width="600" height="250" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"
    ></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: I also had to modify the x and y coordinates, because the canvas see for example e.clientX as the x coordinates starting from the canvas origin and not (like it should be) from the screen origin. It will be probably different for different screen sizes, but for me subtracting 468 from x and 265 from y helped. But there's probably another method to make the coordinates relative to the canvas origin.